# Определить удаленность объекта от места

Tags: геолокация, geo

У меня есть координаты места:

```
55.704219, 37.772379
```

И есть координаты объекта:

```
55.704221, 37.772363
```

Мне нужно определить, насколько (метров) далеко объект находится от места.

Буду благодарен за помощь и полезную информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете какой-либо гео-фреймворк, то такая функция там быть должна. Если руками - формула гаверсинусов [здесь](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

```
a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)
c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
d = R ⋅ c

where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, R is earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km);
note that angles need to be in radians to pass to trig functions!

JavaScript: 
const R = 6371e3; // metres
const φ1 = lat1 * Math.PI/180; // φ, λ in radians
const φ2 = lat2 * Math.PI/180;
const Δφ = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI/180;
const Δλ = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI/180;

const a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
          Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
          Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

const d = R * c; // in metres
```

Comment: А можете посоветовать какой нибудь гео-фреймворк?

Comment: Увы, не могу, не пользуюсь.